# Is this a common pattern in React when calling api, setting state and rendering data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App() {

  const [header, setHeader] =  useState();

  async function fetchDataHandler() {
    const response = await fetch('headerData.json', {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    });
    const data = await response.json()

    const transformedHeaderData = data.header;
    setHeader(transformedHeaderData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataHandler();
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section>
        {header && <Header data={header} />}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am quite new to React. I noticed that we use `{header && <Header data={header} />}` to check that our state is not null, before passing state data to our child component. Is this a common pattern/practice for React developers?

Comment: That is a relatively common way, though personally I prefer showing some subtle "loading" UI rather than just blank space. I'm not sure how exactly we can answer this question, it's a little vague (e.g. If I was to answer the question as currently written, it would just be: "Yes")

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article from better dev](https://www.better.dev/fetch-data-from-an-api-with-react#rendering-api-data) and the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) it is perfectly fine how you fetch and display data. In my personal experience, I also do the same.

Edit: I read a comment on your post, and I don't know how I could've forgotten, you could also display some sort of loader. The syntax is very easy:

```
{header ? <Header data={header} /> : <Loader />}
```

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to evaluate whether header's data is null or has already been fetched.